# Unique field values for subset of documents

Tags: mongodb

Here is a MongoDB query and aggregation puzzle.  Fist some sample records:

```
# Document 1
{
  items: [
    {
      type: "X",
      id: 123
    },
    {
      type: "Y",
      id: 456
    }
  ]
}

# Document 2
{
  items: [
    {
      type: "A",
      id: 789
    },
    {
      type: "B",
      id: 321
    }
  ]
}

# Document 3
{
  items: [
    {
      type: "P",
      id: 987
    },
    {
      type: "X",
      id: 654
    }
  ]
}

# Document 4
{
  items: [
    {
      type: "Q",
      id: 246
    },
    {
      type: "X",
      id: 654
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to find all the distinct `id` values for documents which contain a `type: X` where the `id` is the `id` associated with the `type: X` element.

For example, in the above, what I would like my result to be is:

`[ 123, 654 ]`

These are the unique values of the `id` field associated with the `type: X`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with [unwinding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) your items. Then you can filter out by *type*. In last step you can utilize [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator which will eliminate duplicates.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$items" },
  { $match: { "items.type": "X" } },
  { 
    $group: {
      _id: 1,
      ids: { $addToSet: "$items.id" }
    }
  }
])
```

Grouping with `_id: 1` means that I'm grouping by whatever: I know that everything should be a part of only one group, but I need to use $addToSet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below aggregation to get unique ids.

Query [`$filters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) the items where type is input type followed by [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to project matching item and [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) to extract the id field.

[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) all the items with [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) id values to output the unique values.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([{"$group":{
  "_id":null,
  "ids":{
    "$addToSet":{
      "$let":{
        "vars":{
          "obj":{
            "$arrayElemAt":[
              {"$filter":{
                "input":"$items",
                "cond":{"$eq":["$$this.type","X"]}
              }},
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        "in":"$$obj.id"
      }
    }
  }
}}])
```